# R ggplot2 geom_area() colors beneath a single line produce strange connections

Tags: r, ggplot2

## Description of the problem with an example

Imagine I have this data.frame

```
x <- seq(1, 100) # the indexes
y <- c(seq(1, 25), seq(25, 1), seq(1, 25), seq(25, 1)) # the y values
group_nb <- c(replicate(25, "group1"), replicate(25, "group2"), replicate(25, "group1"), replicate(25, "group2")) # group info
df <- data.frame(x, y, group_nb)
```

That looks like this:

```
x       y        group_nb
-------------------------
1       1        group1
2       2        group1
3       3        group1
```

My ***first goal*** is to plot the line `y` in function of `x` with color depending on the `group_nb`.
My ***second goal*** is to shade the area beneath this line correctly.

The problems I am facing are that I have unwanted connections between points in group1 at index (1:25) and point in group1 at index (50:75).

## 1) Color the line in function of `group_nb`

To color the same line using ggplot, I first tested this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, group=group_nb, color=group_nb)) + 
  geom_line()
```

which gave this plot:

[image: WRONG:geom_line using group colors]

As you can see, there are unwanted connections between points from the same groups.

So I found that by adding `aes(group=1)` to `geom_line()` parameters corrected the problem of the unwanted connections between groups.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, group=group_nb, color=group_nb)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = 1)
```

This gave the plot that I wanted:

[image: CORRECT:geom_line using group colors]

## 2) Color beneath the line in function of `group_nb`

Now I want to be able to shade the area beneath the line with the same colors.
Up until now I have this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, group=group_nb, color=group_nb, fill=group_nb)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group=1)) +
  geom_area()
```

Which makes the same unwanted connections.  We can see that the region with indexes (50:75) is hidden by the shading of group2 but should be the color of group1.

[image: WRONG:geom_area using group colors]

I tried adding `aes(group=1)` to `geom_area()` but it gave me the error `Erreur : Aesthetics can not vary with a ribbon`

So my **questions** are

- How can I solve this?
- Why adding aes(group = 1) in `geom_line()` helps.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your second question first: the groups that ggplot2 interprets are expected to be part of the same geometric element. That is why you can expect `geom_line()` with 2 groups to plot two separate lines for the groups and setting `group = 1` leads to ggplot interpreting as being part of the same geometric element.

That brings me to the first question, what you have might be two groups from a certain perspective, what you want to plot is slightly different. We can fix this by assigning an `id` variable to the data with (for example) run length encoding.

```r
library(ggplot2)


x <- seq(1, 100) # the indexes
y <- c(seq(1, 25), seq(25, 1), seq(1, 25), seq(25, 1)) # the y values
group_nb <- c(replicate(25, "group1"), replicate(25, "group2"), replicate(25, "group1"), replicate(25, "group2")) # group info
df <- data.frame(x, y, group_nb)

id <- rle(group_nb)

df$id <- rep.int(seq_along(id$lengths), id$lengths)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, group=id, color=group_nb, fill = group_nb)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_area(alpha = 0.3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you need the lines/areas to connect, you'd need to replicate the first observation of a group with the ID from the previous group.